# Difference between building distribution packages with python3 and python2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-wheel

I am trying to build  python packages using this [doc](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

I have couple of questions

1. Is there any difference in wheel packages generated using tools(setuptools and wheel) with python2 versus python3.
2. Are packages generated by python3 setup.py bdist_wheel compatible with python2 and vice versa (assuming the source code is compatible with both versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any difference in wheel packages generated using tools(setuptools and wheel) with python2 versus python3.

There may be some byte-for-byte differences due to differing zip compression algorithms, but there is no meaningful difference, except...

> Are packages generated by python3 setup.py bdist_wheel compatible with python2 and vice versa (assuming the source code is compatible with both versions).

By default, a wheel built with Python 2 will only be valid for Python 2, and a wheel built with Python 3 will only be valid for Python 3.  This can be changed by adding the following to the project's `setup.cfg` file:

```
[bdist_wheel]
universal = 1
```

With this option added, generated wheels will be "universal", compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: is universal=1 option available for both python2 and python3?